# How to add compile flag -g to a make file?

Tags: c++, makefile

I got a C++ program for which someone else made a make file. I want to compile the program with flag -g, but I don't know where to add it. Below is the make file.

```
CC = g++
LOADLIBES = -lm
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2


SRC1 = Agent.cpp Breeder.cpp CandidateSolution.cpp \
    Cupid.cpp FateAgent.cpp Grid.cpp Reaper.cpp \
    fitness.cpp

SRC2 = main.cpp

SRC  = $(SRC1) $(SRC2)

OBJS = $(SRC1:.cpp = .o)

AUX = $(SRC1:.c = .h)


main: $(OBJS) 
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SRC) $(AUX) 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o main
```

Where should I add that I want to use -g?

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with C++, so I removed the [c++] tag

Comment: This question is about how to use a Makefile.  There is nothing in this question about the C++ language.  You happen to be using make to build a program written in C++, but the fact that it's written in C++ is orthogonal.  Your code might as well have been written in FORTRAN.

Comment: @JohnDibling I disagree that C++ is orthogonal to this Makefile.  As demonstrated by the answer, Makefiles have special "baked in" syntax specific to C++, and thus Makefiles do have an intrinsic relationship to C++, more so than FORTRAN, particularly when making use of these C++ specific flags as the OP does.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$(CC) is used for compiling C programs. $(CXX) is used for compiling C++ programs. Similarly $(CFLAGS) is used for C programs, $(CXXFLAGS) is used for compiling C++.

Change the first few lines to this:

```
#CC = g++
LOADLIBES = -lm
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -g
```

(But see others' notes about incompatibilities between -O2 and -g.)

Get rid of the spaces inside the parentheses in this line:

```
OBJS = $(SRC1:.cpp=.o)
```

Change the `main` lines to this:

```
main: $(OBJS) $(SRC2)
#   Built by implicit rules
```

---

The resulting makefile should look like this:

```
#CC = g++
LOADLIBES = -lm
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -g


SRC1 = Agent.cpp Breeder.cpp CandidateSolution.cpp \
    Cupid.cpp FateAgent.cpp Grid.cpp Reaper.cpp \
    fitness.cpp

SRC2 = main.cpp

SRC  = $(SRC1) $(SRC2)

OBJS = $(SRC1:.cpp=.o)

AUX = $(SRC1:.c=.h)

main: $(OBJS) $(SRC2)
#   Built by implicit rules

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o main
```

and the output should look like this:

```
$ make
g++ -Wall -O2 -g   -c -o Agent.o Agent.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -g   -c -o Breeder.o Breeder.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -g   -c -o CandidateSolution.o CandidateSolution.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -g   -c -o Cupid.o Cupid.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -g   -c -o FateAgent.o FateAgent.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -g   -c -o Grid.o Grid.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -g   -c -o Reaper.o Reaper.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -g   -c -o fitness.o fitness.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -g    main.cpp Agent.o Breeder.o CandidateSolution.o Cupid.o FateAgent.o Grid.o Reaper.o fitness.o -lm  -o main
```

For completeness, this is the version of make I am using on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i486-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: That outputs `#g++  -o Agent.cpp Breeder.cpp CandidateSolution.cpp Cupid.cpp FateAgent.cpp Grid.cpp Reaper.cpp fitness.cpp main.cpp Agent.cpp Breeder.cpp CandidateSolution.cpp Cupid.cpp FateAgent.cpp Grid.cpp Reaper.cpp fitness.cpp` but does't produce a main file.

Comment: `Makefile:23: *** missing separator.  Stop.` I forgot to mention I use a Mac `GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin10.0`

Comment: The first character on line 23 must be TAB, not a series of spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You need to uncomment the line:

```
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SRC) $(AUX)
```

(remove the hash sigh):

```
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SRC) $(AUX)
```

And change

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2
```

to

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -g
```

But you may find debugging easier if you disable optimization by removing `-O2`:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
```