# Where to add -g flag in vs code for debugging

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I have two questions. I have just installed VS code and managed to make it compile C codes and show outputs. But I am not able to debug. When I add a breakpoint and Debug, Red circle greys out.

[I read on github that adding a -g flag will work](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/416#issuecomment-274580007).

**Q1. But where and how to add  `-g` flag?** I also read:

[How to add compile flag -g to a make file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898287/how-to-add-compile-flag-g-to-a-make-file)

But it passed over my head.

**launch.json:**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/try.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "echo",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json:**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include\\c++"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**tasks.json:**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-Wall", "try.c", "-o", "try"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to change `args` in `tasks.json` from `-o` to `-g`, but it also stopped it from compiling, which was at least working before. If I added besides `-o`, program still didn't debug.

**Edit:**

**Q2. Plus also telll me if it's ok to add path of C++ in `tasks.json` here instead of C?**

Because I couldn't find path for C. Tutorials on internet were for C++ and they told to set C++ path there. But I want to compile C codes and although they are compiling now.

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include\\c++"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should *add* the flag, not replace the `"-o"` flag.

The `-o` flag tells the compiler the name of the output file.

So instead have e.g.

```
"-Wall", "-g", "try.c", "-o", "try"
```

Comment: Great it worked!. Please also answer the question written in Edit section of my question